# Laravel Eloquent; Show the most recent record

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm building a reporting system, to which I import, on a daily basis, a bunch of files into my database. The issue encountered is I may have duplicate but valid records in my database.

In my database I would have the following, example, data set.

```
ID        NAME         MATERIAL      PRICE        CREATED_AT
1         Foo          FP1234        3.45         2016-01-01 15:00:00
2         Bar          FP8177        7.21         2016-01-01 15:00:00
3         Foo          FP1234        4.87         2016-01-02 15:00:00
4         Baz          FP1231        3.00         2016-01-02 15:00:00
```

I would like to know how I can return the above result set, but exclude `row 1` **because** it is the same as `row 3`, and `row 3` is more recent. Adding on to my reasoning, `row 1` and `3` are the same, but since `row 3` has the more recent `created_at` timestamp, I would only want to see this.

The tricky thing is I need to be able to paginate on top of this, and using Laravel's Collection method `forPage` is something I was hoping to avoid.

**Edit**

I can use the Laravel orderBy and groupBy if running a search with an equal too operand, however I need to account for **like** as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try any of these..

```
// For getting result with laravel collection.
YourModel::orderBy('CREATED_AT', 'desc')->groupBy('NAME')->get();

// For getting result without laravel collection.
YourModel::orderBy('CREATED_AT', 'desc')->groupBy('NAME')->get()->toArray();

// For getting result with laravel pagination.
YourModel::orderBy('CREATED_AT', 'desc')->groupBy('NAME')->paginate(5);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `groupBy()` and `orderBy()` methods. You can try something like this:

```
Model::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->groupBy('name')->get()
```

Comment: You have a spelling mistake grouBy('name')